# Removing all items in an Arraylist to remain with one

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've done some research before posting this, but I still haven't quite grasped it yet. Basically I have 4 items in my Arraylist:

Bananas, Oranges, Apples and Pineapples

```
ArrayList<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
  addItems(){
    fruitList.add("Banana");
    fruitList.add("Oranges");
    fruitList.add("Apples");
    fruitList.add("Pineapples");
}
```

and I am trying to remain only with one. This is what I've tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fruitList.size() - 1; i++) {
        fruitList.remove(i);
    }
```

from my understanding the code above should remove 3 items, however I get 2 items; (Oranges and Pineapples).

Kindly help me understand this in achieving the desired result.

Comment: Start `i` at `size()-1` and then iterate to 1. Since you are removing elements, the second will become the first, and then you'll increment `i` and skip over one. Also as it is your loop iterates over the whole list since you are using `<=`

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Which one should remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the index goes up from the beginning of the list, while the size of the list is shrinking:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i <= fruitList.size() - 1; i++) {
>     fruitList.remove(i);
> }
> ```

Not only it's confusing which elements get removed,
it's also very inefficient to remove elements from the middle of a list like this.

It would be better to use an index going from the end, as the other answer suggests.

A compact way to achieve the same is to use a sub-list and clear it:

```
fruitList.subList(1, fruitList.size()).clear();
System.out.println(fruitList);
// prints [Banana]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the items but the 1st:

```
for (int i = fruitList.size() - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    fruitList.remove(i);
}
```

iterate backwards so the index is in sync with the changing size of the list.
If you do this:

```
int size = fruitList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    fruitList.remove(0);
}
```

you will remove all but the last, because at each iteration you remove the 1st item until there is only 1, which will not be removed.